# How to convert python distutils.core function call "extension" to a gcc command

Tags: python, c++, gcc

How to convert python distutils.core function call "extension" to a gcc command

So I use a third party python library that uses a script that calls distuils to install the library

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension("okhound",
                    sources = ["pyOkHound.cpp"],
                    libraries = ["PhraseSpotter"],
                    library_dirs = ["."])

setup(name = "OkHound",
      version = "1.0",
      description = "'Ok Hound' phrase spotter.",
      ext_modules = [module1])
```

Upon some investigation I find out that the result of the script is a output.so file. Since we are using a cross-compiler with make files for our target machine, I am trying to find a way to do what the script does in gcc. 
I have access to the PhraseSpotter.a file and pyOkHound.cpp file and was wondering how to get the output.so file like the above script did?

What is setup doing behind the scene?

Update
Things I have tried:

```
gcc -o output -l PhraseSpotter main.o
gcc -c -fPIC pyOkHound.cpp -o pyOkHound.o
gcc -shared -o output.so -fPIC pyOkHound.cpp
```

But they do not link the libraries with the source like the extension command did. 
I am not sure how the link the static library to the cpp file.

Comment: I have PhraseSpotter.a and pyOkHound.cpp in the same directory

Comment: Can you cheat and put another `gcc` on your `PATH` that’s just a shell script that shows its arguments?